# Delphi XE3: Convert WideChar array to Unicode string HOWTO?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I've done some research here regarding the problem given above and come up with the following code:

```
VarStr = array of WideChar;

function ArrayToString(const a: VarStr): UnicodeString;
begin
  if Length(a) > 0 then
    begin
      ShowMessage ('Länge des übergebenen Strings: ' + IntToStr(Length(a)));
      SetString(Result, PWideChar(@a[0]), Length(a) div 2)
    end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

ShowMessage displays the correct number of characters in a given array, but the result of the function is always an empty string.

Your ideas please?

Comment: `Length(a) div 2` means that only half of the characters are used. Rather than `PWideChar(@a[0])`, you can perfectly well write `@a[0]`. The cast is needless. However, the code will produce a runtime error if the array of is length 0 and you use range checking. Which you should. So I'd write this as `PWideChar(a)`.

Comment: what's the content of a[0] , #0?

Comment: @bummi I don't think that matters `SetString` doesn't look for null terminators

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mhhmm. with a[0]=#0 (or not initialized, maybe he is not aware of 0 based) you will get an empty string as described, not a shortened string.

Comment: @bummi No you will not. Try it and see. Starting from the code in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not going to argue, he is talking about `Showmessage`, just try `a[0] := #0;
  a[1] := 'b';
  a[2] := 'c';
  a[3] := 'd';
  Showmessage(ArrayToStringBroken(a));`

Comment: @bummi OK, that could be true. I read *the result of the function is always an empty string* and took it at face value. But I suppose that asker is likely not using debugger or Writeln and is indeed check values with `ShowMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Result:= Trim(string(a));
```

**UPDATE:** As colleagues graciously pointed in comments, this is a **wrong** answer! It works only because internal string and dynamic array implementation are pretty similar and there is no guarantee that such code would work in  the future compilator versions. The correct way to DynArray->String conversion is described in the David answer. I would not delete my answer to preserve comments, in my opinion their worth is much greater..

Comment: The Trim seems erroneous. I suggest that you remove that.

Comment: Trim function seems necessary, however last character is dropped.

Comment: @Stefan I don't believe what you report

Comment: Without Trim function it's runtime error 216 - not compiling was my mistake (sorry, with Delphi I'm still a learner).

Comment: @Stefan That's not what I see here. Runtime error 216 is access violation.

Comment: Without Trim it should work just as well. Trim also should not eat last character (it does not do that in my test example). There is something fishy with your VarStr array.

Comment: David's answer is correct. I've added termination character and set counter +1 in code above. Thx!

Comment: @Stefan That comments makes no sense to me. Why did you add a termination character? Where did you add it? Where is the +1? Why did you do that?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of `UnicodeString` and `string` being synonyms. The important thing you're demonstrating here is that it's OK to type-cast a dynamic array to tell the compiler it's really a string even though `string` and `array of WideChar` are *not* synonyms. That's not necessarily intuitive.

Comment: Type-casting a dynamic array to a `string` is wrong. If you are going to do that, type-cast the array to what it is really compatible with - a `PWideChar`, eg: `Result := UnicodeString(PWideChar(a));`. Either typecast requires the array to be null terminated, though. If it is not, you have to use `SetString()` instead (which you should he using anyway).

Comment: What Remy said, in a nutshell. Null terminated, zero-indexed *static* arrays of Char are (by design) compatible with string, but dynamic arrays are not. The fact the code in this answer appears to work is because the internal format of a dynamic array of Char is similar to the internal format of a string, but that's an implementation detail which should never be relied upon - indeed, the confusion about whether the cast should be wrapped in a Trim call and/or be involved in appending an explicit null terminator hints at this.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for your interjection here. I fell for the string cast too and can now see the error of my ways.

Comment: An `array of Char` is not a `string`, and is not converted to a proper `string` during such a type-cast. All it is doing is tricking the compiler into thinking the array's memory pointer is pointing at a `string` payload, but it does not. If you trace into your example, you will see that the array pointer is passed as-is to `System._Write0UString()`, which passes the pointer as-is to `System._LStrFromUStr()`, which *happens* to work because a dynamic array has a `length` field at the same memory offset that a `string` does, but that conversion will only work for an `array of Char`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated my answer to reflect them.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the wrong length value. You only ask for half of the characters. Fix your code like this:

```
function ArrayToString(const a: VarStr): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, PWideChar(a), Length(a));
end;
```

However, you also report that your function returns an empty string. The most likely cause for that is that you are passing invalid input to the function. Consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  VarStr = array of WideChar;

function ArrayToStringBroken(const a: VarStr): UnicodeString;
begin
  SetString(Result, PWideChar(@a[0]), Length(a) div 2);
end;

function ArrayToStringSetString(const a: VarStr): UnicodeString;
begin
  SetString(Result, PWideChar(a), Length(a));
end;

var
  a: VarStr;

begin
  a := VarStr.Create('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
  Writeln(ArrayToStringBroken(a));
  Writeln(ArrayToStringSetString(a));
end.
```

The output is:

```
ab
abcd
```

So as well as the problem with the code in your question, you would seem to have problems with the code that is not in your question.

Perhaps when you said:

> The result of the function is always an empty string.

You actually meant that no text is displayed when you pass the returned value to `ShowMessage`. That's a completely different thing altogether. As @bummi points out in comments, `ShowMessage` will truncate its input at the first null-terminator that is encountered. Use proper debugging tools to inspect the contents of variables.

Comment: In XE7, `var a: VarStr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];` looks a lot better!

Comment: FWIW, that is equivalent to the older syntax `a := VarStr.Create('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');` which is, again, equivalent to your code using `SetLength(...); a[0] := ...;`

Comment: It is easy to forget them. I hardly use them, because they do not optimize anything. It is just a little less typing. I prefer to initialize my dynarrays from a constant array and write a little routine that either copies element by element or moves to the dynarray, depending on the base type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I have a static generic class that inherits from `TArray<T>`, is also called `TArray<T>`, and allows me to write: `arr := TArray<Integer>.Copy([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Comment: I don't, but it is a good idea. But that is equally non-performant, as the values are "generated" at runtime. But how do you inherit from TArray<T> (a generic dynamic array)?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ah, I got that wrong. I inherit from `Generics.Collections.TArray` which is a class full of static generic methods. Sloppy of me. So the call looks like this: `arr := TArray.Copy<Integer>([1, 2, 3, 4])`. As for generated at runtime, it's going to be hard to avoid that for a dynamic array surely. Is the new XE7 functionality any more performant?

Comment: As I said, the numbers can be stored in a constant and then moved into the dynarray at runtime. Beats having to push an array on the stack at runtime, i.e. something equivalent to `PUSH 'a'; PUSH 'b'; etc...; MOV EAX,ESP; MOV EDX,4; CALL MyFunc`, which is what usually happens with open array constructors.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis So far as I can tell the only perf improvement comes from being able to declare constant dynamic arrays. So, `arr := [1, 2, 3, 4]` produces the same code as the dyn array constructor.

Comment: If the array is bigger than a few elements, having a constant array that is moved into a dynarray as one block is more performant, IMO. I feel there should have been syntax that allows the assignment of a constant to a dynarray which would, internally, exactly do this.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well, that syntax exists now, as of XE7

Comment: Not really. That new XE7 syntax does exactly the same as your manual initialization, i.e. it generates an assignment for each element, i.e. at runtime, it does `SetLength(a, 4); a[0] := 'a'; a[1] := 'b'; etc.`. It does not (block) copy from an already existing constant. But that is what I'd like to see.

Comment: @Rudy try declaring a constant dyn array and assign it to a var. I mean using `const`. It's quite different. Although I've not yet worked out quite what a const dyn array is.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Assignment of const dyn array to var is turned into a call to `System._DynArrayAsg` which (eventually) becomes a call to `Move`.

Comment: I didn't know about a **const** dyn array yet. I knew the new synatx, but never tried to define a constant in it.

Comment: Hmmm... But IIRC, `_DynArrayAsg` normally simply assigns one pointer to another and updates the refcount. Or am I wrong there? I'm in my clinic right now, without XE7, so I'll have to check this later.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In the case of a constant array, it copies it. Of course, constant arrays did not formerly exist so the `_DynArrayAsg` you know did not have any code to deal with them, what with them not existing and all!

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look as soon as I'm home. Thanks for telling me this, it could be what I have been looking for.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Seems that the new functionality has some bugs. I just found this: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9806

Comment: Indeed. FWIW, I tried to have a (dynamic) TWordArray as field in a record and then to define a record constant with the syntax. The compiler did not accept it. But I could define a TWordArray alone as constant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I also found this one, https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9809 which is interesting when viewed alongside https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9806